# Bootstrap Vue b-form-select display json objects

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So I'm trying to display b-form-select with :options of a list of json objects. Its showing null for all options, and the v-model does not store to anything due it not know what value to store.

```
<b-form-select v-model="dropDownSelected" :options="listOptions"></b-form-select>
```

listOptions is an array of json objects

dropDownSelected is just a value. The listOptions is being populated properly via axios

```
axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Item/?search='+term
        }).then(response =>{
          console.log('idRequest Data: '+response.data);
          if(response.data){
            this.listOptions = response.data
          }
          if (this.listOptions.length === 0) {
            console.log('LIST OF ITEMS EMPTY')
          }
        }
```

How do I display the list of objects in b-form-select properly, and have the v-model store a specified value?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the value of response.data?

Answer (score 0):

The `b-form-select` by default waiting for array of objects that has two property: `text` and `value`.
I think your data from the api is in a wrong structure.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select

If that's the problem you can create a computed property to transform and get back your `listOptions` in the right structure or you can transform it after you loaded from the server.

Comment: I see thanks. This is what I ended up doing! Thanks!